# PHP Combine 2 arrays based on their values

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I need to combine based on their values.

They look like this:

First:

```
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [AAA] => 1000
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [BBB] => 1000
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [CCC] => 10
        )
}
```

Second:

```
Array
(
    [CCC] => 5145
    [AAA] => 451
    [BBB] => 3020
}
```

What I would like to do is go through both arrays, compare their AAA, BBB, CCC values and if they are the same create third array that will look like this:

```
   Array
    (
        [8] => Array
            (
                [AAA] => 1000,
                [AAA_2] => 451
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [BBB] => 1000,
                [BBB_2] => 3020
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [CCC] => 10,
                [CCC_2] => 5145
            )
    }
```

Any ideas on how this can be done? Tried using array_combine() with no luck.

Comment: So try something else. Simple `foreach` for example.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Iterate your array using `loop` and create a new output array

Answer (score 0):

I seem your code and try to create third array as per your mention and it ok on my site. please refer the below code and check them.

```
$first = Array('8' => Array('AAA' => 1000),
              '12' => Array('BBB' => 1000),
              '14' => Array('CCC' => 10));
$second = Array('CCC' => 5145,
                'AAA' => 451,
                'BBB' => 3020);
$third = array();
foreach ($first as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
      if(array_key_exists($k,$second)){
          $third[$key] = array($k => $v, $k.'_2' => $second[$k]);
      }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($third);
```

Answer (score 0):

This task only requires one foreach loop, not two.  `$first` will be the output array.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67261e1c27c76d011173a1a733347813cc0792c1))

```
$first=[8=>["AAA"=>1000],12=>["BBB"=>1000],14=>["CCC"=>10]];
$second=["CCC"=>5145,"AAA"=>451,"BBB"=>3020];
foreach($first as &$a){  // modify $first subarrays by reference
    $k=key($a);  // temporarily store first element's key
    if(isset($second[$k])){  // if key is found in $second
        $a["{$k}_2"]=$second[$k];  // add assoc element to $first
    }
}
var_export($first);  // display updated $first array
```

Output:

```
array (
  8 => 
  array (
    'AAA' => 1000,
    'AAA_2' => 451,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'BBB' => 1000,
    'BBB_2' => 3020,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'CCC' => 10,
    'CCC_2' => 5145,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Hopefully it works.

$first = array(8=>array("AAA"=>1000), 12=>array("BBB"=>1000),14=>array("CCC"=>10));

$second = array("CCC"=>5145,"AAA"=>451,"BBB"=>3020);

foreach($first as $fKey => $fVal){

```
foreach($fVal as $k => $v){

    if(array_key_exists($k, $second)){
        $newKey = $k."_2";
        $first[$fKey][$newKey] = $v;
    }
}
```

}

print_r($first);

Comment: Every single post you have made (today at least) has been poorly formatted and includes no explanation.  These are bad posted answers.  You need to improve all of your answers before continuing to litter SO with more sloppy posts.  While there will be people that will clean up after you, you need to take some responsibility and clean up your own messes.